# How to zoom in on current position on load of page

Tags: javascript, openlayers, dom-events, openlayers-3

I am new in open-layer I am trying to zoom in on current location on load on page I don't want to use any button, I was trying to get the output when I load a page it will redirect to my current location with zoom level 12.
I tried to change the view by calling function but it is not working for me.

I tried below on load on page but it is not working:

```
  el('track').addEventListener('load', function() {
    geolocation.setTracking(this.load);
  });
```

Comment: you have  `var view = new ol.View({center: [0, 0], zoom: 2});` why don't you just update `zoom`?

Comment: i can but i want it zoom in on current position. center cordinate should be users position

Comment: see answer below, i think that's what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do two things.

Firstly, add `tracking: true` to the following.

```
var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation({
    projection: view.getProjection(),
    tracking: true
  });
```

then add this line `map.getView().setCenter(geolocation.getPosition());` to the following function.

```
  geolocation.on('change:position', function() {
    map.getView().setCenter(geolocation.getPosition());
    var coordinates = geolocation.getPosition();
    positionFeature.setGeometry(coordinates ?
      new ol.geom.Point(coordinates) : null);
  });
```

See [updated plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/VdGSGVyVDXTxXSBg5pJI?p=preview).

Comment: hay Paul, can you please help me with the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45801218/how-to-load-point-on-map-on-change-of-input-value

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple function instead of Openlayers "track" example which assigned for check box.

```
function gL() {
  geolocation.setTracking(window.load);
}
```